# How does Energy Field interact with effects that say you lose life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How does [Hissing Miasma](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHissing%20Miasma%5d) affect a player protected by [Energy Field](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnergy%20Field%5d) if their creatures are attacking?

Additionally, how does [Tainted Remedy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTainted%20Remedy%5d) affect Energy Field if same player does something to gain life?

Answer (score 5):

In both cases Energy Field does nothing because both Hissing Miasma and Tainted Remedy cause loss of life and not damage, so Energy Field can't prevent it.

Damage to players causes them to lose life (assuming the source doesn't have infect), but loss of life isn't always damage.

> **118.2.** Damage dealt to a player normally causes that player to lose that much life. See rule 119.3.
>
> **118.3.** If an effect causes a player to gain life or lose life, that player’s life total is adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Hissing Miasma will continue to make the attacking player lose 1 life.  Losing life is not the same as damage. Since it's losing life and not damage, Energy Field doesn't come into play here.

Answer (score 1):

Energy Field has no interesting interaction with either Hissing Miasma or Tainted Remedy. Energy Field only prevents damage, while the effects of Hissing Miasma and Tainted Remedy both directly cause life loss.

Damage causes life loss, but not all life loss is damage.